# Sharepoint - CQWP to point to current site

Tags: 2007, content-query-web-part

In an ONET.XML file I build a page with a CQWP.  The CQWP has a WebUrl property is there a way to set this to alway be the the current web?

I tried this but it didn't work.s

```
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="g_LeftCell" WebPartOrder="1" >
      <![CDATA[
      <webParts>
...

<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~Site</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ~SiteCollection and ~Site are valid tokens.

```
<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~sitecollection</property>
```

for root site or

```
<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~site</property>
```

for current subsite